# How can we estimate (conditional) probabilities from a dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, estimation, dataset

Given three random variables $X$, $Y$ and $Z$, how can we estimate $P(X)$, $P(X\mid Y)$ and determine whether $P(X \mid Y, Z) = P(X \mid Z)$ from a dataset (of e.g. $N$ observations) which contains features $X$, $Y$ and $Z$?

To estimate the conditional probability, I think we need to filter on the variable we are conditioning on. For example, in the case of $P(X \mid  Y)$, we look at $X$ for all values of $Y$. But how exactly do we estimate $P(X \mid  Y)$?

I think an example would definitely be very useful.

Answer (score 3):

In the case of $P(X)$, if $X$ is discrete, then it takes a finite number of values $\{ x_1, x_2, \dots, x_m \}$. Then we can count how many observations have $X=x_1$, $X=x_2$, etc. In this case, we can estimate $P(X=x)$, for some $x \in \{ x_1, x_2, \dots, x_m \}$, so we can also estimate the distribution of $X$ (i.e., essentially it would be a histogram).

Similarly, we can also estimate $P(X \mid Y)$. For each value $y \in \{y_1, \dots, y_t\}$, we calculate $P(X \mid Y=y)$, that is, for each $y$, we count how how many observations have $X=x_1$, $X = x_2$, etc.

To estimate the conditional independence given a third variable, that is, $P(X \mid Y, Z) = P(X \mid Z)$, we again do a similar thing. First, we estimate $P(X \mid Z)$ as above, then we estimate $P(X \mid Y, Z)$. How do we estimate $P(X \mid Y, Z)$? For each combination of $y \in \{y_1, \dots, y_t\}$ and $z \in \{ z_1, \dots, z_r \}$, we can count the number of $X=x_1$, $X = x_2$, etc.

Comment: Ahh.  OK.  That's great.  It's totally fine to answer your own questions if you figure out the answer on your own.  I just thought perhaps that you were needing something additional or perhaps intended to add to the questions instead of to the answer.  You just typed out an an answer way more quickly than I would have been able to so quickly after asking, so I was a bit confused.!  ;-) One might be able to take a different approach if you can make distributional assumptions about $X, Y$, and $Z$.  Is that possible or is nothing known about $X, Y$, and $Z$?

Comment: That's great, @nbro!  Nice work.  Did you see my question about distributional assumptions in my previous comment?  Some alternative answers might be appropriate if we can make those assumptions.

Comment: You explain that we need to count the number of observations in particular bins to estimate the P(X) and P(X|Y). But... how do we finally determine whether P(X|Y,Z) = P(X|Z)?

Comment: You do not calculate P(X|Y, Z) and P(X|Z) exactly. What you calculate are *estimates* of P(X|Y, Z) and P(X|Z). So what if these estimates are different by a tiny bit? That situation might be very likely to occur, even when P(X|Y, Z) = P(X|Z).

Comment: So is this a good way to 'determine whether P(X∣Y,Z)=P(X∣Z) from a dataset' if it fails most of the time and does not include the almost equal cases where there is "a chance that they might be equal"?

Comment: Say you have two fair six sided dices, one red and one blue. So the probabilities to roll a particular number are all 1/6. 

$$P(X=a)  = P(X=a|red)  = P(X=a|blue) = \frac{1}{6} $$

when you take a *sample*, say you roll 1000 times a red dice and 1000 times a blue dice. Do you believe that it is likely to get *exactly* equal counts or proportions? 

$$\frac{n(X=a|red)}{1000} = \frac{n(X=a|red)+ n(X=a|blue)}{2000}$$

Comment: Yes I could have used one dice. That is sort of the point. That your comparison is neither working when taking two independent samples from the same population (I used two dice because your question relates to testing whether different populations, e.g. different dice, different values $Y$, have the same distribution). You may expect some variance and both samples being equal does often not occur. This is however how you seem to write down your test (compute the sample statistic/counts/number and compare whether they are equal).

Comment: Could you clarify in your question what conditions are necessary for an answer? The question is currently very broad (e.g. estimates of population means and population parameters that can be used to define P(X) and P(X|Y) depend greatly on the distribution or the type of problem). What sort of statement satisfies? What is expected from an estimate? Do you look for a point estimate or an interval estimate. Bayesian or frequentist? Optimize p-value, power or false discovery rates? Etc. The current question-answer is unclear. It is a very crude and unusual method.

Comment: Estimation  (of the probabilities) and hypothesis testing (of the equalities between the probabilities) can be performed in many different ways. How it should/can be done depends on circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

One way to deal with this is using a contingency table with counts of the events. Say the variables are categorical: $X \in  \lbrace 1,...,l \rbrace$, $Y \in  \lbrace 1,...,m \rbrace$, $Z \in  \lbrace 1,...,n \rbrace$ then you could put the numbers of observations $n_{xyz}$ in the categories $x,y,z$ for a given $z=i$ in a $l $ by $m $ contingency table:

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc|c}
& y=1 & y=2 & \cdots &y=m &  \\ \hline 
x=1 & n_{11i} & n_{12i} &&n_{1mi} & n_{1\cdot i}\\ 
x=2 & n_{21i} & n_{22i} &&n_{2mi} & n_{2\cdot i}\\ 
\vdots & &  && &\\ 
x=l & n_{l1i} & n_{l2i} &&n_{lmi} & n_{l\cdot i}\\ \hline 
 & n_{\cdot1i} & n_{\cdot2i} &&n_{\cdot mi} & n_{\cdot\cdot i}
\end{array}$$

where the $n_{ijk}$ are counts of the joint events $x=i$, $y=k$ and $z=k$. A dot like  $n_{\cdot jk}$ relates to marginal sum.

---

Then the probabilities could be estimated by ratios of those counts.

$$P(X=i|Y=j,Z=k) = \frac{n_{ijk}}{n_{\cdot jk}}$$

(NB for other type of distributions than the categorical distribution there can be better approaches)

---

The equality or independence can be determined in several ways (the same is true for estimating the probabilities). There is no general method for this and you would need to specify the problem and needs more specifically in order to decide on the right test.

Examples are [Pearson's chi-squared test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test) or the 
 [Cochran-Mantel-Haenszel test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%E2%80%93Mantel%E2%80%93Haenszel_statistics).
The second is a more specific test than the first and is for a three-way relationship with two binary variables.